# Ionic 4 ion-select popover position

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using a `ion-select` with attribute `interface="popover"`.
The popover is opening up below the `select` which makes the popover very small.

I figured out that if there's 10 or more items in the `ion-select`, it open downwards, while there's less than 10 items it calculates which way to open, depending on where the most space available is vertically from the `select` input.

How can I set the popover to open above the `select`?

Screenshot of **Source** opening below `select` (wrong way):

[image]

Screenshot of **Method of Contact** opening above `select` (correct way):

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code for the ion-select?

Answer (score 4):

When `interface="popover"` is like that, Ionic 4 uses `ion-popover` component here. As version Ionic 4.x, there is no built-in things to position this window. So you need to override the core behavior. To do so, please add the snippet to your page's CSS file.

```
.popover-wrapper .popover-content{
    position: relative !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
    top: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the click event and use it inside `presentPopover` method

template:

```
<your-element (click)="presentPopover($event)"></your-element>
```

component:

```
async presentPopover(event: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
        component: PopoverComponent,
        event
    });

    return await popover.present();
}
```